# C# Windows Application - Get Webbrowser Control Values

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, timer

I have two dropdown controls in my Website. For example consider one is country and another one is state. State dropdown data will be load based on the selected country.

Using C# windows Webbrowser control, I have accessed that website and can able to get the all the country dropdown values using GetElementById('ddlCountry')

Then I have write code to iterate all country dropdown values and Invoke change event.

Now My Question is How can I Get the each state values from state dropdown for each country dropdown change event.

Comment: How this question is related to its title? There's nothing about timer here.

Comment: Dennis, I have tried with Timer Call back Method but no result happen. So that only I ddn't mention in header.